# How to merge two duplicate columns from different tables AND keep duplicate rows - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL (I've looked all over the other questions about merging columns and I think my issue might be slightly different).  I am trying to Join two tables, and only data from 3 of the columns ("QuantityOnHand", "WarehouseID", and "WarehouseCity") from these two tables, but, one of the columns in each of the two tables are identical ("WarehouseID"), with identical information.  When I run my query, I get 4 columns (because the column "WarehouseID" is duplicated).  However, I need to only have one column that shows "WarehouseID".  I figured out how to get past the ambiguous problem of Joining two tables that have the same name of "WarehouseID", but I don't know how to merge the duplicate column (I'm not even sure if merging is correct, I just need to drop the duplicate column)   My query looks like this:

```
SELECT i.QuantityOnHand, i.WarehouseID, w.WarehouseID, w.WarehouseCity
FROM inventory i
JOIN warehouse w ON i.WarehouseID = w.WarehouseID
WHERE i.QuantityOnHand >= 200
ORDER BY i.QuantityOnHand desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop the duplicate ID, you simply need to omit it from the SELECT portion of your statement. You don't have to select a column simply because it appears in your join clause. I believe you could achieve what you're looking for with the statement:

```
SELECT i.QuantityOnHand, w.WarehouseID, w.WarehouseCity
FROM inventory i
JOIN warehouse w ON i.WarehouseID = w.WarehouseID
WHERE i.QuantityOnHand >= 200
ORDER BY i.QuantityOnHand desc;
```

Note that I just omitted one of the WarehouseID columns from your statement. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!  This solved my issue exactly!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  I thought you had to put in the WarehouseID for each of the tables, because it was in both tables.  I was staring at this and researching this for 3 hours.  Thank you so much!!